# Irrreducibility of resultant

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, resultant

> Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a commutative ring with unity, $f(x),g(x)\in\mathbf{A}[x]$. Denote Res($f,g$) be the resultant of $f$ and $g$. Assume that the coefficients of $f$ and $g$ are indeterminates and let $A[f,g]$ be the ring generated by these coefficients. Show that $\operatorname{Res}\left(f,g\right)$ is irreducible over $A[f,g]$.

This is a useful fact to know, as it implies that any polynomial in $A\left[f,g\right]$ that vanishes whenever $f$ and $g$ have a common root will be a multiple of $\operatorname{Res}\left(f,g\right)$, at least when $\mathbf{A}$ is an algebraically closed field. But how is it proved?

Comment: So you have a polynomial ring $\mathbf{A} = K\left[f_0,f_1,\ldots,f_n,g_0,g_1,\ldots,g_m\right]$ over some given integral domain $K$, and you define the polynomials $f\left(x\right) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n f_k x^k \in \mathbf{A}\left[x\right]$ and $g\left(x\right) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^m g_k x^k \in \mathbf{A}\left[x\right]$, and you want to show that $\operatorname{Res}\left(f,g\right)$ is irreducible as an element of $\mathbf{A}$. I think the following argument works: ...

Comment: ... Let $\mathbf{B}$ be the subring $K\left[f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_n, g_0, g_1, \ldots, g_m\right]$ of $\mathbf{A}$. Let $\mathbf{p}$ be the ideal of $\mathbf{B}$ generated by $g_0, g_1, \ldots, g_{m-1}$. Then, $\mathbf{p}$ is a prime ideal (since the quotient $\mathbf{B} / \mathbf{p}$ is a polynomial ring over $K$ and thus an integral domain). Write $\operatorname{Res}\left(f,g\right)$ as the determinant of the Sylvester matrix, and expand this determinant using the Leibniz formula. The addend corresponding to the identity permutation will be $f_0^m g_m^n$ (if this differs from what you get, ...

Comment: ... we are probably using different conventions, but the argument should go through mutatis mutandis), whereas each other addend belongs to $\mathbf{p} f_0^k$ for some $k < m$ (in fact, it contains at least one of $g_0, g_1, \ldots, g_{m-1}$, and it cannot contain $m$ instances of $f_0$). Now, regarding $\operatorname{Res}\left(f, g\right)$ as a degree-$m$ polynomial in $\mathbf{B}\left[f_0\right]$, we should be able to apply Eisenstein's criterion (specifically: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein's_criterion#Generalized_criterion ). The only difficulty is to check that the constant ...

Comment: ... term does not belong to $\mathbf{p}^2$. This, I believe, can be done as follows: From each of the first $m$ columns of the Sylvester matrix, pick the $f_1$. From the subsequent column, pick $g_0$ (the top entry). From the remaining columns, pick a $g_m$ each. The resulting addend $\pm f_1^m g_0 g_m^{n-1}$ contributes to the constant term of $\operatorname{Res}\left(f, g\right)$, and is not cancelled by any other addend (there is only one permutation yielding it). Notice that we need $m$ and $n$ to be positive for this to work, but the other case is obvious.

Comment: @darij grinberg You should group your sequence of comments into an answer, preserving its "chatting" style.

Comment: "expand this determinant using the Leibnitz formula", do you mean Leibnitz formula in expand $(u.v)$ -nth derivative? @darijgrinberg

Comment: @Zootopia: No, that would be the Laplace formula. I mean the Leibniz formula that expands a determinant as a huge sum over all permutations.